# How to connect the point with a line on plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I was trying to plot this dataframe on R and then connect the dots together with a line for having a development graph showing how the number of film per year has changed. Im gonna upload a foto of my dataframe [image: dataframe] and of my code below

```
plot(fpa, type = "p", xlab="Year", ylab="Film Per Year")
```

with this code i have the first plot [image: plot1]. But if i change type to b for both then the result i get is the second plot.[image: plot2] .

To be precise i was trying to have a plot like this one [image: plot3].

Comment: It's most useful to supply a reproducible R example, not just a screenshot of your data (so provide us with the variable `fpa`), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, have a look at packages such as `ggplot2` or `highcharter` for more powerful plotting tools!

Comment: fpa its the result of using a select query on a postgres db table i created. I've tried with ggplot2 but i get problems with that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to order your x-axis first:

```
set.seed(111)
fpa = data.frame(Anno=sample(2000:2018),FilmPerAnno=rnbinom(19,mu=10,size=1))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(fpa, type = "b", xlab="Year", ylab="Film Per Year",main="not ordered")
plot(fpa[order(fpa$Anno),], type = "b", xlab="Year", ylab="Film Per Year",
main="ordered")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally forgot about that part. Thank you for your help